# How to loop in multiple directories with a for loop using os.walk()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I created a script which is supposed to loop in different directory and then in the sub-directories of the initial directory  and find the files to process. The graph is like this :

```
1. Embeddings_test  # general directory
   > sm  # first level of directory
     > or # second level of directory
         > file 1
         > file 2

     > aug
         > file 1
         > file 2

     > or_et_aug
         > file 1
         > file 2

   > bc  # first level of directory
     > or # second level of directory
         > file 1
         > file 2

     > aug
         > file 1
         > file 2

     > or_et_aug
         > file 1
         > file 2

....
```

What I want to do is to loop inside each sub-directories and retrieve the files inside but somehow , the loop stop at the first sub-directory : "sm" and "or" and do not loop in the others that is "aug" and "or_et_aug".

Results :

```
----------------
------------------Directory : sm ---- or
------------------
['flaubert-small-cased_emb_corpus_or_test.pkl', 'flaubert-small-cased_ylabels_corpus_or_test.pkl']
---file for emb--- :  flaubert-small-cased_emb_corpus_or_test.pkl
---file for labels--- :  flaubert-small-cased_ylabels_corpus_or_test.pkl
10 fold cross validation in processed ----------

Model name: Model_SVC_ovr
------------cross val predict used----------------
---------------cross val score used -----------------------
[1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   0.75 1.  ]
0.97 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.07
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
------------------
------------------Directory : bc ---- aug
------------------
------------------
------------------Directory : unc ---- or_et_aug
------------------
```

Code lines

```
# Loading features and classes

mod = ['sm', 'bc', 'unc', 'lg']

corpus = ['or','aug','or_et_aug']

for m, c in zip(mod, corpus):
    print("------------------")
    print("------------------Directory :", m, "----", c)
    print("------------------")
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("/ho/get/kelo/eXP/Test/embeddings_test" + "/" + m + "/" + c):
        #print(root)
        print(files)
        print("---file for emb--- : ", files[0])
        with open(os.path.join(root, files[0]), 'rb') as f1:
            features = pickle.load(f1)
        print("---file for labels--- : ", files[1])
        with open(os.path.join(root, files[1]), 'rb') as f2:
            ylabels = pickle.load(f2)
        # cross validation training and testing

        print("10 fold cross validation in processed ----------", "\n")
        models_list = classifiers()
        for model_name, model in models_list.items():
            print("Model name: {}".format(model_name))

            print("------------cross val predict used----------------")
            # cross val score : Run cross-validation for single metric evaluation

            print("---------------cross val score used -----------------------")
            scores = cross_val_score(model, features, ylabels, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv_splitter)
            print(scores)
            print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
            print("-------------------------------")
            print("-------------------------------")
            print("-------------------------------")
            print("-------------------------------")
            print("-------------------------------")
```

I expected to print result for each directories and then sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure `zip` is the function you need?

```
import pathlib as pth
import itertools

ROOTDIR = pth.Path("/ho/get/kelo/eXP/Test/embeddings_test")

mod = ['sm', 'bc', 'unc', 'lg']
corpus = ['or','aug','or_et_aug']

for m, c in itertools.product(mod, corpus):
    root = ROOTDIR / m / c
    files = [file for file in root.iterdir() if file.is_file()]
    print(root)
    print(files)
```

I will describe my code later.

Comment: Thank you but could you explain what the code do  ? For what I saw, it get the pkl file in all the directory. But My aim was to process files according to the directory they are to seperate them and do not be  confused with whihc files I am using

Comment: By the way , executing your lines produce nothing!!